# When should i sync my data from parse.com to my android app

Tags: android, mobile, parse-platform

I'm making an android application whith parse.com. Here is the situation : I have an offline part on my android app and i'm using LDS (LocalData Storage) to stock my data and send them to parse.com. But other data can be send to parse.com from the website and i need to sync them with my app.

So my problem is to know when to request data from parse.com without making it too heavy for the app and still have a good UX.

I've been thinking about multiple solutions :

- Put a sync button on the application
- When the user log in for the first time i request all the data from parse and after that on the other log i merge using the last updated date.
- When the user change of view i asked parse.com on all the data about this view and this only ?
- I update all the data every X minutes

I would like to have your opinion about the right way to get my data sync knowing that i have an offline mode on my app.

Thanks! And sorry for my english ><

Comment: Consider asking such questions on http://programmers.stackexchange.com since it's not problem with code, but more of a software design question.

Comment: Thanks for the idea i put a post there too